# docker php, nginx is super slow with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker

I have create a simple docker stack: php, nginx, mariadb

each one has its own container.

Now I run on this stack a simple wordpress app,
but the site loads SUPER SLOW ~ 4-5 sec

I looked through

```
docker stats
```

and stats looks good max 15% cpu usage, and memory barely getting to 5%

I have all the docker-compose and dockerfiles here:

https://gist.github.com/tzookb/f4a868ae06a474676afbb4fce8055902

would be happy to get any ideas on why this is so slow.

** docker on macbook pro

Comment: On OS X there are problems with docker. My friend has OS X and have similar problems as you

Comment: docker has so much hype, and still it works bad on Mac?? most developers use mac....

Comment: most developers of what? Most php developers use Linux ;)

Comment: :D still I thought docker will be much better with all that hype around it

Comment: docker originally use linux containers which are native for linux. Trying to emulate it on different systems than linux is quite obvious it won't be as fast as on Linux

Answer (score 4):

I was trying out Docker on my Macbook Air recently and **it is superslow**. Are you mounting a folder with Wordpress to Docker? Then that's the problem.

Mounting drives on Docker seem to be an issue on OS X. You can find a tons of complaining on this around, for example this thread: https://forums.docker.com/t/file-access-in-mounted-volumes-extremely-slow-cpu-bound/8076

The only thing I recommend is **to stop using Docker**, it's not a reliable option on Mac right now.